# error on discord presence extention vscode

Tags: discord, vscode-extensions

so, discord has profile status right? I want my status to show vscode and what i'm working on, there's a vscode file extention for it called "discord presence" and based on the vieos i've watched, it should automatically sync up with your discord account and update your profile status [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X290w.png) but when i install the extention. [it's saying this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIUc4.png) please help.

ps. both my github and discord accounts are under the same gmail. idk if that helps or not.

I tried to uninstall and install again and reloading vscode and discord but nothing fixed it.